# How do I categorize user input in C#

Tags: c#, string, variables, input

I've learned how to store a single input of data and return a value based on it.

What I want to do is obtain multiple inputs from the user, then return a result. But how do I define each input?

Like, if I want the first input to be known as 'stock', and the second as 'value', how do I do that?

I hope I explained my question properly.

Comment: You need to radically improve your explanation here. What exactly is the context, what are the specifics of your algorithm, etc. From what you have now...no one is going to have a clue what your talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string stock = Console.ReadLine();
string value = Console.ReadLine();
```

.. Or am I interpreting your question incorrectly?

Edit: As a response to your comment:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine(); //enter stock value
string[] parts = input.split(new String[]{ " " });

stock = parts[1];
value = parts[2];
```

If you wish to actually define a "new" variable named "stock" and give it the value "value", you should look into `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<key, value>`

Comment: So when it's run, each input will be stored in that order? Basically, I want to make sure that if I have it say "Enter stock value" it will store the data input there as stock and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If @ItzWarty's answer isn't quite what you want, this would allow your users to enter multiple values in one line:

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();

//whatever chars you wish to split on...
string[] inputs = line.Split(new char[] {' ', ',', ';'}); 

string stock = inputs[0];
string value = inputs[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
        string name = String.Empty;
        string department = String.Empty;
        int age = 0;


        Console.WriteLine("Please, enter the name of your employee, then press ENTER");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please, enter the department of your employee, then press ENTER");
        department = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please, enter the age of your employee, then press ENTER");
        Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age); // default 0


        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name);
        Console.WriteLine("Department: " + department);
        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + age.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is all starting to make sense to me. I do apologize if my question was too vague or lacked enough information, but you have provided several good answers here. I really appreciate it.